# XQuery - remove all characters (illegal) that are NOT {A-Z,a-z,_,0-9}

Tags: regex, xquery

I need an XQuery that removes any characters that are NOT {A-Z,a-z,_,0-9} - without having to explicitly specify them in the query.

Currently I am using:

```
for $x in /xml/TEST
let $i := concat('M', replace($x/ID, '[\[\]\(\)°: ]', ''))
return element {$i} {$x/* except $x/ID}
```

But whenever a new illegal character creeps up I need to adjust that command... so: not perfect.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In regex you can use a negated character class by adding a carat `^` before the characters to be negated that will do exactly what you want:

```
replace($x/ID, '[^A-Za-z_0-9]', ''))
```